# Изменение ширины ContentDialog - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

В программе создаю Contentdialog.

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="Clinic.Add_Shedule"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Clinic"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Расписание"
    PrimaryButtonText="Сохранить"
    SecondaryButtonText="Отмена"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick" DefaultButton="Primary">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="500">
      //Тут различные элементы
    </StackPanel>

</ContentDialog>
```

Когда меняю ширину Stackpanel то меняется и ширина окна, но больше 500 поставить не удается. Можно как то обойти это ограничение? Может есть другие варианты как создавать подобные окна.

Comment: А если самому `ContentDialog` задавать `Width`?

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогает.

Comment: А если `MinWidth`?